# Extract letters from a field and make it on another

Tags: java

```java
public class Driver {
    // fields

    private String Id;

    Id = name.substring(0, 3);

    public Driver(String f1, String f2, int f3, String f4) {
        // constructor
    }
}
```

Well, I've changed the code. It's much clear.
I want to extract the first three letters from nomC, the first letter from prenomC and the last two digit from anneeEC and make them on a new field. Why it shows an error on line « private String numId; »: Syntax error on token ";",, expected?

Comment: This question seems too localized to me, listen to your compiler error, you defined your "String = nomC.substring(0, 3);" wrong (You're assigning to the type string... doesn't make much sense does it?)

Comment: I know. I didn't copy the right code. I've changed it, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put

```
  firstThree = nomC.substring(0, 3);
```

inside the constructor.

Comment: +1, @mpluse Because the constructor is where you set an object's properties. Your code was outside the constructor made no sense in Java

Comment: No problem :) Please have a look at some tutorials on Java objects, constructors, classes, etc. You will learn better if you investigate issues like this by yourself rather than rushing to ask questions. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

> Why it shows an error on line 2?

Because a declaration must include a variable name, not only its type:

```
String firstThree = nomC.substring(0, 3);
```

Comment: Oww! Sorry, I've made numId. It doesn't work. Even firstThree.

Comment: @mpluse You may want to edit the question then to show some more of your code.